# Jest: Testing Toolbar Menu component doesn't simulate click event

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm having troubles testing a Menu toolbar component when its clicked, it has a boolean `open` prop.

So I'm trying by this wway:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    shallowWrapper = shallow(
      <Router>
        <Toolbar />
      </Router>).dive(styles);
    mountWrapper = mount(
      <Router>
        <Toolbar />
      </Router>);
  });

  it('should change state when Menu button is clicked', () => {
    expect(mountWrapper.find('Menu').props().open).toBe(false);
    mountWrapper.find('Menu').simulate('click');
    expect(mountWrapper.find('Menu').props().open).toBe(true);
  });
```

My Menu component:

```
<Menu
  id="menu-appbar"
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  anchorOrigin={{
  vertical: 'top',
  horizontal: 'right',
  }}
  transformOrigin={{
    vertical: 'top',
    horizontal: 'right',
  }}
  open={open}
  onClose={this.handleClose}>
  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Log out</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

I tried both, shallow and mount and no one works, I got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$wcgrpuavu7' of null
```

It found the 'Menu' correctly but it doesn't simulate a click, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: what does your `Menu` component code look like? One thing to bear in mind is that `simulate()` will only work on the node that has the relevant listener attached (in your case, an `onClick`) - the "event" will not bubble up like a real DOM event.

Comment: Sorry I'm not using the line props.onClick = jest.fn();.. actually I have other components that has that prop but this not. I edited the context

Answer (score 0):

I think your actual onClick is inside Menu component. In unit testing you should unit test component isolating other components.

So in this case yo approach should be:

```
it('should change state when Menu button is clicked', () => {
expect(shallowWrapper.find('Menu').props().open).toBe(false);
shallowWrapper.instance().handleClose();
// Now here check data modified from handleClose button
});
```

Can't see your handleClose  else would have written last section of test as well.

Comment: sorry I edited the context I haven't a onClick prop on my component

Comment: I think still you use this approach to unit test. I think you are modifying value of open inside handleClose  function.

Comment: yes handleClose just do that, sets open value to true or false